# In the place of checkboxDisplay heading need to replace with a text box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

- I am new to kendo ui
- I am trying to display a text box on the first column heading.
- In the place of checkboxDisplay heading I need to replace with a text box.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/on7zbd43/

```
<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->


    columns: [{
        field: "checkboxDisplay",
        title: "checkboxDisplay",

        template: "# if ('new' =='new') { # <input id = 'checkIDGrid' type='checkbox' checked=true class=''> # }else{# <span class='oldEventArrow'></span> #} #"


      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowTemplate` to change template of kendoUI

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr data-uid="#= uid #">
        <td colspan="2">
            <strong>#: name #</strong>
            <strong>#: age #</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ],
  rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html())
});
</script>
```

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/rowtemplate

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/on7zbd43/14/)